# Program freezes when running as I try to input file contents into listbox

Tags: c#, file-io, listbox

I'm trying to add the contents of this file into a listbox but everytime I do, it freezes the application. I put a watch on the variable lines and that contains the data I want to input but it reads it from the file, the error occurs.

```
        {

            StreamReader inputfile;

            inputfile = File.OpenText("ClosingStock.txt");

            while (!inputfile.EndOfStream)
            {
                string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("ClosingStock.txt");
                SummaryClosinglistBox.Items.Add(lines).ToString();
            }
            
        }

Any help would be very much appreciated.
```

Comment: Just remove the inputFile and the useless loop. Just try to read the lines. If the file is empty nothing will be added. If you need to check for file exist then use File.Exists

Comment: you never read from inputfile - so how should it ever reach its end?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to programming. I thought that File.ReadAlllines is reading the file? My file is 13 columns by 5 rows of ints. Is there a better way I could output this data to a listbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This loop condition will cause an infinite loop because you never change the EndOFStream on the inputFile variable

```
while (!inputfile.EndOfStream)
```

The fact that you read the line with File.ReadAllLines doesn't mean that  *inputFile* stream advances to reach the end of stream. ReadAllLines open its own stream, reads everything and then closes its internal stream. So you just need to read the lines, eventually add a check on file existance. An empty file will do nothing because no line will be added. But if you really want you can add a check on the number of lines as well.

```
if(File.Exists("ClosingStock.txt"))
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("ClosingStock.txt");

    if(lines != null && lines.Length > 0)
        SummaryClosinglistBox.Items.AddRange(lines);
}
```

Notice that to add a set of items to the ObjectCollection you should use AddRange not just Add

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I also want to add a space between each element and remove the comma. Is there a way that I could do this? Sorry for the additional question.

Comment: You can use [string.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split) and then reassemble the line with [string.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join). You can find lot of examples on SO.

Comment: Thank you very much. Have a great day!